# where to get deployment logs of azure app service VS-Code extension

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

i have a react site that am trying to deploy to azure app service (free tiers windows) plan.
i am using VS-Code's Azure App service extention.

when i right click deploy to web app i get the error

```
11:44:47 AM amn-react-app: Starting deployment...
11:44:47 AM amn-react-app: Creating zip package...
11:53:39 AM amn-react-app: Zip package size: 298 MB
11:53:40 AM: Error: An error has occurred.
```

where to see the deployment logs to check what happened ?

**update**
following the update below i was able to see logs but they still not telling details.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use vscode create a sample react project to test.

**And I found, we can check delpoyment logs on portal.**

## Method 1

[image]

## Method 2

I also try to use rest api to get deployments info, but failed because I don't find deployment id. If you are interested, you can also try.

[Web Apps - Get Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getdeployment)

Comment: i added an update. i was able to see these logs but doesn't explains much that what is going on,

Comment: @RaasMasood From your screenshot, it seems that the log file was manually deleted during the publishing process. It is recommended to click `show logs` after re-publishing.